How can I diagnose what slows down the computer?
My laptop with Arch Linux and GNOME is sometimes slow, so it takes a long time to launch applications, load webpages &c., there are stuttery animations, and text input is noticeably delayed. I can't figure out what causes this because it happens also when the CPU is not fully used, there is plenty of free memory, and not much data is read from or written to the SSD. These are the data which I can see in System Monitor.
How can I figure out what causes these slowdowns? I have no idea of what it could be, maybe bad configuration of the scheduler, some random writes to memory by a piece of software or a hardware failure.

I figured out that the system is slow because the CPU frequency is stuck at 400 MHz. I have no idea of what causes it. It may be related to that my system can't detect the CPU cooling fan, but it seems not because of thermal throttling because the CPU doesn't overheat.

You can start trying using htop or atop which are available for archlinux. These can show you which processes are giving you issues (or resource hogs).
command: sudo pacman -Ss htop
Ref: https://runcloud.io/blog/running-processes-in-linux
If your investigation into the possible process "hogs" doesn't give you any clues, then it might be a hard disk/SSD issue. Often when loading/executing applications for the first time with "plenty" of CPU/Memory that gives you bad performance, is often a symptom of a failing drive.

there is a free software 6MB used for CPU and RAM burning, stressing and benchmarking. System Stability Tester Monitor temperature of your CPU, GPU, and other critical components, Track the fan speed and ensure your system is adequately cooled during the test, Monitor voltage levels to identify any potential power supply issues. Keep an eye on overall system power consumption.

The system computes alright, it is just not responsive.

I figured out that the system does not compute alright. The CPU frequency is stuck at 400 MHz.
